# function to make text and lists appear when certain item is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have two recipes and i am trying to make them show up only when the relevant option is selected from a drop down menu. I have the code for the recipes and the drop down menu but I'm not sure how to link the two but without using jQuery or any other external libraries. Thanks

```
<select id="myList" onchange="favsports()">
<option> Macaroni Cheese</option>
<option> Mushroom and Spinach Lasagne</option>
</select>

<div id="rec">
<p> Macaroni Cheese </p>
<p> Ingredients </p>
<ul>
  <li>175g Pasta</li>
  <li>50g Butter</li>
  <li>50g Plain Flour</li>
  <li>400ml Semi-skimmed Milk</li>
  <li>175g Cheese</li>
</ul>  

<p> Method </p>
<ol>
  <li>Pre-heat the oven to 180ºC</li>
  <li>Cook the pasta </li>
  <li>In a different pan melt the butter</li>
  <li>Add the flour and cook for onw minute on the hest</li>
  <li>Take off the heat and add the milk, a little at a time</li>
  <li>Retur to the heat and bring to the boil, stirring the whole time</li>
  <li>Once bubbles appear, add the cheese and stir it all in until its melted</li>
  <li>Season to taste </li>
  <li>Mix together with the pasta and bake in the oven for 20 minutes</li>
</ol>  


<p> Mushroom and Spinach Lasagne </p>
<p> Ingredients </p>
<ul>
  <li>1 tbsp Olive Oil</li>
  <li>1 Garlic Clove</li>
  <li>250g Mushrooms</li>
  <li>1 tsp Thyme Leaves, chopped</li>
  <li>200g Bag of Spinach</li>
  <li>300g Tub of Light Soft Cheese</li>
  <li>4 tbsp Grated Parmesan</li>
  <li>6 Fresh Lasagne Sheets</li>
</ul>  

<p> Method </p>
<ol>
  <li>Heat oven to 180ºC</li> 
  <li>Heat the oil in a large frying pan, add the garlic and cook for 1 min. </li>
  <li>Add the mushrooms and thyme, then cook for 3 mins until they start to soften.</li> 
  <li>Throw in the spinach and stir until the heat of the pan wilts the leaves. </li>
  <li>Remove from the heat and stir in the soft cheese, 1 tbsp of the Parmesan and some seasoning.</li>
  <li>Put a quarter of the spinach mix on the bottom of a medium-sized baking dish, lay 2 pasta sheets on top, then repeat until you have used all the pasta.</li> 
  <li>Finish with the final quarter of the spinach mix and sprinkle over the rest of the Parmesan</li>
  <li>Bake for 35 mins until golden and the pasta is tender.</li>
</ol> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to do your assignment for you.  However a starting point is you need to use javascript in addition to your current html.  Also, you need to add the value attribute to the option tag:

```
<select id="myList" onchange="favsports()">
<option value="mac"> Macaroni Cheese</option>
<option value="lasagne"> Mushroom and Spinach Lasagne</option>
</select>
```

Then you need to create a javascript function like the "favsports()" one you have listed in your question.  Inside that function you will need to figure out how to tell which option is selected and you will need to wrap each recipe in its own `<div>` tag so you can show/hide them appropriately.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbqoswkh/11/)

You need to wrap the elements you want to show and hide and then it's just as easy as checking what value is selected and toggling the css..

Code:

```
<select id="myList" onchange="recipe()">
<option></option>
<option> Macaroni Cheese</option>
<option> Mushroom and Spinach Lasagne</option>
</select>

<div id="rec">
<div id="macandchee">
<p> Macaroni Cheese </p>
<p> Ingredients </p>
<ul>
  <li>175g Pasta</li>
  <li>50g Butter</li>
  <li>50g Plain Flour</li>
  <li>400ml Semi-skimmed Milk</li>
  <li>175g Cheese</li>
</ul>  

<p> Method </p>
<ol>
  <li>Pre-heat the oven to 180ºC</li>
  <li>Cook the pasta </li>
  <li>In a different pan melt the butter</li>
  <li>Add the flour and cook for onw minute on the hest</li>
  <li>Take off the heat and add the milk, a little at a time</li>
  <li>Retur to the heat and bring to the boil, stirring the whole time</li>
  <li>Once bubbles appear, add the cheese and stir it all in until its melted</li>
  <li>Season to taste </li>
  <li>Mix together with the pasta and bake in the oven for 20 minutes</li>
</ol>  

</div>

<div id="shroomsandspinach">
  <p> Mushroom and Spinach Lasagne </p>
  <p> Ingredients </p>
  <ul>
    <li>1 tbsp Olive Oil</li>
    <li>1 Garlic Clove</li>
    <li>250g Mushrooms</li>
    <li>1 tsp Thyme Leaves, chopped</li>
    <li>200g Bag of Spinach</li>
    <li>300g Tub of Light Soft Cheese</li>
    <li>4 tbsp Grated Parmesan</li>
    <li>6 Fresh Lasagne Sheets</li>
  </ul>  

  <p> Method </p>
  <ol>
    <li>Heat oven to 180ºC</li> 
    <li>Heat the oil in a large frying pan, add the garlic and cook for 1 min. </li>
    <li>Add the mushrooms and thyme, then cook for 3 mins until they start to soften.</li> 
    <li>Throw in the spinach and stir until the heat of the pan wilts the leaves. </li>
    <li>Remove from the heat and stir in the soft cheese, 1 tbsp of the Parmesan and some seasoning.</li>
    <li>Put a quarter of the spinach mix on the bottom of a medium-sized baking dish, lay 2 pasta sheets on top, then repeat until you have used all the pasta.</li> 
    <li>Finish with the final quarter of the spinach mix and sprinkle over the rest of the Parmesan</li>
    <li>Bake for 35 mins until golden and the pasta is tender.</li>
  </ol> 
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var recipe = function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("myList");
    var rec = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(rec);
  if(rec == "Mushroom and Spinach Lasagne"){
    document.getElementById("shroomsandspinach").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("macandchee").style.display = 'none';
  }
  if(rec == "Macaroni Cheese"){
    document.getElementById("macandchee").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("shroomsandspinach").style.display = 'none';
  }
  if(rec == ""){
    document.getElementById("macandchee").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("shroomsandspinach").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

There's definitely a more elegant solution to this, but this should get you started.